# XBee S2C (XB24C) Router-Coordinator Dont send or receive any message

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I have 2 XBEE S2c module like these ->
[Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YZc5.jpg)

I installed XCTU latest software from the internet and set one of the XBee is router, other one is coordinator. I gave them exact same id 4444. After looking tons of website i couldnt communicate them. My friend got same XBees and i used those configurations but still not working. Is my XBee Modules are broken?

Here are the settings; 
For Router:
https://ibb.co/album/k5mgDS

For Coordinator:
https://ibb.co/album/7QmcR0


Terminal Example ( Coordinator Send and Receive at the same time but Router dont sending or receiving anything. )

[Terminal 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTOcl.png)

[Terminal 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozAaW.png)

They both connected to the computer like this;
[Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDg7j.jpg)

I look for a solution in all websites, and tried everything but did not find anything useful. With same configuration my friends devices can able to communicate but mine doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**:

this is exactly my problem (Connection related between Coordinator - Router)

***Note : Kindly Check Firmware Version

if Version is greater than 4060 then downgrade to 4060***

*i don't know the reason*

**i downgraded to ver 4060 then it works ...**

**and most important Change AP (API Enable) to
0
(Transparent mode)**

And Config guide -- > For **Co-Ordinator**
(Suggestion From Robu.in)
1: *First set Pan ID for your network.* This can be any Hex value from 0 to FFFF. (Set it as 1234)

2:To operate the Radio in the broadcast mode set the DL (Destination address) as *FFFF*.

3: Type the name of the first radio in NI (Node Identifier).

4:You can provide any name. Here the NI set as *COORDINATOR.*

5:To make the Radio as COORDINATOR, Set the **CE parameter to *Enable*** and click on the Write button (Pencil Icon) to save the information.

Config Guide --> For **Router**

1:Enter the Pan Id [Same as Coordinator] **which is the same as COORDINATOR**.

2:Set the JV channel Verification to **enable** so that it joins the COORDINATOR.

3:Leave the CE to **Disable** and click on the Write to save the changes.

That's It !

now Check Serial Communication ...

---

Problem 2: (My Suggestion [cause it happened with me also])

and for [Coordinator Send and Receive at the same time]

Check **COORDINATOR Config DL (Destination Address)** -> Set to **FFFF**

Comment: Hello. I did everything you said but it was still not working. Seems one of the devices is broken or burned circuit.